# Using class functions without initialization

Tags: nestjs

I have this typescript code (just an example, similar to mine):
**(read comments)**

```css
telegram.service.ts
```

```js
import {ExampleService} from 'path/to/ExampleService';
import {Update} from 'nestjs-telegraf';

@Update()
export class TelegrafModule {
    constructor(
        private readonly exampleService: ExampleService, // Doesn't require any arguments!
        @InjectBot() private bot: Telegraf<Context>
    ) {}
    async test() {
        example.test(true);
    }
}
```

```css
telegram.module.ts
```

```js
import {Module} from '@nestjs/common';
import {TelegrafModule} from 'nestjs-telegraf';

import {TelegramService} from './telegram.service';
import {ExampleModule} from 'path/to/ExampleModule';
@Module({
    imports: [
        TelegrafModule.forRootAsync({
            useFactory: () => ({
                token: settings.bots.token,
                middlewares: [sessionMiddleware],
                launchOptions: {
                    webhook: {
                        domain: settings.bots.domain,
                        hookPath: '/telegram',
                    }
                }
            }),
        }),
        ExampleModule.register()
    ],
    providers: [TelegramService],
})
export class TelegramModule{}
```

But when i try to replicate similar thing in other file:

```css
layouts.telegraf.ts
```

```js
import { ExampleService } from 'path/to/ExampleService';

const exampleService = new ExampleService(); // Error, because ExampleService requires inputing arguments into it, but it didn't before!

export async function test() {
    exampleService.ping(true); // Without `const exampleService...`(line 3 this file) line it just doesnt know what exampleService is, and we cant use exampleService here
}
```

How to fix that?
I would be happy to hear any suggestions!

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what Nest is doing under the hood for you. Nest is passing all of the necessary parameters to the constructor of the classes and keeping tabs on what instances exist. So in your first example, Nest has ended up calling `new ExampleService(param1, param2, ...paramN)` for you already. If you want to use the `ExampleService` _outside_ of the DI context, you need to pass all those parameters yourself. This is just how classes work

Comment: `exampleService: ExampleService` is just a type declaration for `exampleService`  parameter, while `new ExampleService()` it's a concrete usage. You can't compare them. I suggest you to learn about javascript classes, and typescript in general.